# String bending on an acoustic?

Tags: guitar

my exercise book had me trying to bend strings up two half steps. I have to use all my strength to even do one half step, and to do this I have to push the string all the way to the adjacent string. I'm already using the lightest gauge strings.

Is there something I'm missing or does he probably intend it to be done only on electric?

Comment: Which strings in particular? Is it an acoustic guitar exercise?

Comment: A whole tone should be possible to bend even with thicker gauges. Touching the adjacent strings when bending is to be expected.

Comment: When bending you sometimes need to use the tip of your finger to [push the adjacent strings out of the way](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/GsldbstYEog/hqdefault.jpg) so they don't touch the string you are bending.